# where do I add add_header directives to in shared hosting environment

Tags: apache, http-headers

I have seen some results from security scans that a client website is not behaving as securely as possible.

The security scan suggests to resolve this, we need to add some `add_header` directives, e.g:

```
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin" always;
```

In a shared server environment, can I add these to `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

Affirmative, in environments where you might not have direct control over the Apache server such as in shared hostings  you can use .htaccess and enforce headers from there.

Take a look at this:
https://torbjornzetterlund.com/hardening-your-http-response-headers-with-htaccess/